# How do I formulate logistic quantile regression models?

Tags: logistic, modeling, quantile-regression

Which of these models is most appropriate given the data (prediction is my goal), and why? I haven't had much experience with quantile regression, and I have so far assumed (probably niavely) that they can be treated the same as OLS regression models to a degree. I would like to fit logistic quantile regression models to these data:

```
 df <- structure(list(PropDead = c(0.528504072010287, 0.458851264466352, 
    0.474924989284183, 0.657093870552936, 0.630304329189884, 0.603514787826832, 
    0.99464209172739, 0.726746678096871, 0.839262751821689, 0.828546935276468, 
    0.774967852550364, 0.882126018002572, 0.903557651093013, 0.941063009001286, 
    0.989284183454779, 0.946420917273896, 0.866052293184741, 0.882126018002572, 
    0.978568366909559, 1, 0.973210458636948, 1, 0.957136733819117, 
    0.99464209172739, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Live = c(88, 101, 98, 64, 69, 
    74, 1, 51, 30, 32, 42, 22, 18, 11, 2, 10, 25, 22, 4, 0, 5, 0, 
    8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dead = c(99, 86, 89, 123, 118, 113, 186, 
    136, 157, 155, 145, 165, 169, 176, 185, 177, 162, 165, 183, 187, 
    182, 187, 179, 186, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187), TrtTime = c(3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
    10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14), RepNumber = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

with the eventual goal being prediction. However, I am unsure if my model formula is appropriate as I can't find any tutorials on whether or not I should include polynomials with quantile regression, or how to do this if I should.

This is what my data looks like:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(y = PropDead, x = TrtTime, colour = factor(RepNumber)))
```

[image]

I have tried a few different models so far:

```
#Simple logistic regression
time.lqr <- Log.lqr(y = df$PropDead, x = cbind(1,df$TrtTime), p = 0.99)

#Trying to include a quadratic curve to the fitted line.
poly.lqr <- Log.lqr(y = df$PropDead, x = cbind(df$TrtTime, poly(df$TrtTime, 2)), p = 0.99)

#Log transformed time variable to straighten it.
logtime.lqr <- Log.lqr(y = df$PropDead, x = cbind(log(df$TrtTime)), p = 0.99)
```

I know that the lqr models fit *robust* logistic regression models (and that there is a "best" alternative- see `lqr::Log.best.lqr`) but I wasn't sure exactly what this mean and I also haven't been able to find any packages that fit non-robust alternatives.

**Question:**

1. Which of these models are appropriate, if any, given the data?
2. Can I (or should I) be using the raw Live/Dead counts rather than the proportion? If so, how? I get an error when I try cbind like I would for a binomial glm.
3. Are there other more appropriate models?

To clarify these are not the only models that I am using - I have a suite of models and I am trying a range to see which works best (defined by minimising prediction error), but I would like to include quantile regression in this comparison.

Comment: To clarify - I have some understanding of robust modelling in that I understand that they are less influenced by outliers... my lack of understanding is more around the best part and whether a robust model would have much influence on the outcome in my situation.

Comment: Choosing a quantile model may be similar to choosing models with OLS with linear terms and non-linear terms might be best decided by 1) plotting the model over the data to see which looks more appropriate. 2) evaluating goodness of predictions as you indicated. 3) compute AIC to see if additional terms are worth including.

Comment: Far as linearizing variables, this is not a requirement for quantile regression but it might mean you can leave out non-linear terms from your model and model becomes simpler

Comment: A note of caution when using quantile logistic regression is how to interpret the results. It can be abit tricky to express to others that predictions are on the distributions of probabilities rather binary outcome. See @Frank Harrell's comment here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128924/how-binary-quantile-regression-divides-the-dependent-variable-into-quantiles